# extreme bounds package in R

Tags: r, package

I am new in R and I need to learn to use the Package ‘ExtremeBounds’. I am using the tutorial mtcars dataset to learn and as I am doing different exercises I continuously get this error

```
Error in reg.summary$coefficients[variable.label, 1] : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

If i do

```
eba(data = mtcars[1:32,], y = "mpg", free = "wt", doubtful = c("cyl","disp","hp","drat","qsec","vs","am","gear","carb"), focus = c("hp","gear"), k = 0:3, mu = 0, leve = 0.85)
```

I don't get the error, but when I try to do the following, i get the error

```
eba(data = mtcars[1:8,], y = "mpg", free = "wt", doubtful = c("cyl","disp","hp","drat","qsec","vs","am","gear","carb"), focus = c("hp","gear"), k = 0:3, mu = 0, leve = 0.85)
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I would really appreciate it as I need to use this package for a school project.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This is a collinearity problem. When you use only the first 8 data points **cyl** and **vs** exactly determine the value of **gears**, which causes an internal error in the function code. There is no way of getting around this issue. You either have to use more data or you cannot have **gears** as a focus variable. Alternatively, you could remove either **cyl** or **vs** from the doubtful variables and the function will work then as well.

Comment: does R report somewhere which variables are responsible for the error message?